# SQLSTATE[HY093] after update to Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm getting
`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

```
select * from `starters` where `dummy` != 4 and `events_id` = 11
order by `dummy` asc, time_all, (error_1 + error_2), `time_1` asc`
```

after updating my laravel 8 projekt to Laravel 9, the code is

```
$starters = \App\Models\Starters::where('dummy','!=', 4 )
    ->where('events_id',request()->events_id)
    ->with('events')
    ->with('drivers')
    ->with('cars')
    ->orderBy('dummy','asc')
    ->orderByRaw('time_all','asc')
    ->orderByRaw('(error_1 + error_2)','asc')
    ->orderBy('time_1','asc')->get();
```

can't see the problem, any suggestions?

Comment: As a note, you can combine your with statements into one by passing an array with the related models

Comment: `public static function orderByRaw($sql, $bindings = [])` Remove `asc` from your `orderByRaw`, that's the default sort anyway, and the raw function uses bindings as the second parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your orderByRaw() clause cannot have backticks like you have here:

```
->orderByRaw('(error_1 + error_2)','asc')
```

Try it like the following:

```
$starters = \App\Models\Starters::where('dummy', '!=', 4)
    ->where('events_id', request()->events_id)
    ->with('events')
    ->with('drivers')
    ->with('cars')
    ->orderBy('dummy', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('time_all', 'asc')
    ->orderByRaw('(error_1 + error_2) asc')
    ->orderBy('time_1', 'asc')->get();
```